# Executing mount system call from perl

Tags: linux, perl, system-calls, mount

How can the `mount` system call be done from perl? The following:

```
$ret = syscall(&SYS_mount, "/proc", "/path/to/my/mount/point", 0, 0, 0);
```

results in:

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at ...
```

I cannot call the `mount` program using `system` because I need to make a `mount()` system call that the `mount` program doesn't seem to be capable of. More specifically, I need to call:

```
mount("/proc", "/path/to/my/mpoint/point", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE|MS_BIND, NULL);
```

But if I try to run the following with an unprivileged unshared mount linux namespace:

```
mount --make-rprivate --bind /proc /path/to/my/mountpoint
```

Then I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /proc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Using `strace` reveals that what the `mount` program actually does is to call:

```
mount("/proc", "/path/to/my/mountpoint", ..., MS_MGC_VAL|MS_BIND, NULL);
mount("none", "/path/to/my/mointpoint", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL);
```

But this splitting of options does not work. I need `MS_BIND` and `MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE` in a single call to the `mount` system call for it to work in an unprivileged unshared mount namespace.

So how can I do my initial system call in perl without the error message about an attempt of a modification of a read-only value?

**edit**:

Thankfully ikegami was quick to point out what i did wrong when trying to use perl's `syscall` function but in case somebody finds this when searching for how to bind mount a directory from within an unprivileged mount namespace with just the `mount` command line utility, here is how:

```
mount --rbind /proc /path/to/my/mountpoint
```

This in turn will call the following syscall internally:

```
mount("proc", "/path/to/my/mountpoint", ..., MS_MGC_VAL|MS_BIND|MS_REC, 0);
```

The `MS_MGC_VAL` flag just seems to be for backwards compatibility with kernel versions prior to 2.4. The important bits are `MS_BIND` (for doing the bind mounting itself) and `MS_REC` (for doing it recursively so that directories that have their content hidden by other mounts being done into them do not have their content exposed in the mount namespace).

So now I have to decide whether I go with a perl `system` function call or just do the `mount` systemcall because both work just as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`syscall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syscall.html) refuses to pass a pointer to the string buffer of a constant since it has no idea if the argument is `char *` or `const char *`.

> You can't use a string literal (or other read-only string) as an argument to syscall because Perl has to assume that any string pointer might be written through

The solution is simple. Just copy the constant into a variable first.

```
my $ret = syscall(&SYS_mount, my $s="/proc", my $t="/path/to/my/mount/point", 0, 0, 0);
```

Test:

```
$ perl -E'
   require "syscall.ph";
   my $ret = syscall(&SYS_mount, "/proc", "/path/to/my/mount/point", 0, 0, 0);
   say $ret;
'
Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 3.

$ perl -E'
   require "syscall.ph";
   my $ret = syscall(&SYS_mount, my $s="/proc", my $t="/path/to/my/mount/point", 0, 0, 0);
   say $ret;
'
-1

$ strace perl -e'
   require "syscall.ph";
   syscall(&SYS_mount, my $s="/proc", my $t="/path/to/my/mount/point", 0, 0, 0);
' 2>&1 | grep mount
mount("/proc", "/path/to/my/mount/point", NULL, 0, NULL) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: You sir/madam just made my day! I now see that the docs of `syscall` say "You can't use a string literal (or other read-only string) as an argument"... silly me, I should've RTFM... Nevertheless, since you just saved me many headaches I wish you many upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full implementation in Perl here: https://github.com/i-MSCP/imscp/blob/1.5.x/engine/PerlLib/iMSCP/Mount.pm